# How to keep plist stored in documents directory in sync between iPhone & iPad for universal app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, plist, icloud, ios-universal-app

I have a setup in which I have a single `plist` file that I need to be kept in sync between devices for a universal app. At present the `plist` file is stored in the documents directory.

I have been looking around online for ways to keep the file in sync and a lot of solutions seem to be based around `Core Data`. I'm not sure if it's possible, but is there a way I can just sync this one file without using `Core data`? If so, please can someone advise on how to approach the problem or point me in the direction of some materials that can assist?

To be more specific I need a way of ensuring that the device being used has the most up to date copy of the plist file. For example, if I edit it on my iPad at breakfast, then at lunch time I load the app on my iPhone I should see the edits made at breakfast time via my iPad.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sync..? like a user who has this app installed on his iphone and ipad..?

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud automatically backs up all the documents directories for all apps (or selective) on your device if you have iCloud Backup turned on in settings.

But the above things happen I guess once in a day. In order for it to work real time you will have to use iCloud API's.

Hoping this helps.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you will require to provide the iPhone/iPad app with server APIs for making a POST request. You can POST the entire file or create POST request with body (JSON/XML) containing actual data from plist file. You will have to maintain ETag/Versioning information on the server. For synching to work, you need to identify each user uniquely on the server and store his plist information.

In the iPhone/iPad app during every app launch check for the resource ETag (in case file is uploaded) or for version (in case plist file contents were posted as XML/JSON) by making a HTTP request. You can also develop a scheduler functionality in the application for better precision. In case of update, download and save the new information/plist file. Keep entry for ETag/version in the application NSUserDefaults and update it during this process.

**Friendly advice**: Avoid storing any downloadable data/settings in **Application_Home/Documents** directory as app may get rejected. Please read this [post](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/local-file-storage-in-ios-5) and related documents on Apple's developer portal.

This is just initial thought, improvising and optimizing this is for you to figure out ... :)
I hope this helps!

Cheers!!
Amar.